# 'Static' template class in a template class — encapsulation, inheritance or …?

Tags: c++, templates, static

I have a 'static' template class alike the following:

```
#include <cstddef>

template <size_t elem_size>
struct StaticClass
{
    static void* priv;
};
```

So, the class contains only static members. As the static template implies, there should be one `priv` variable for each `elem_size`.

I also have the main template class which is already inherited from another class:

```
template <class T>
class MainBase
{
    // types, methods...
};

template <class T>
class MainDerived : public MainBase<T>
{
    // members, methods...
};
```

Now, I'd like `MainDerived` to be able to access `StaticClass<sizeof(T)>`; with the implication that different types `T` of the same size will access the same variable. **What is the most optimal method of doing so?** I'm mostly thinking about memory footprint.

AFAICS, having a non-static `StaticClass<sizeof(T)>` member in `MainDerived` increases the class size by 1 (for the size of 'static' class is 1).

So I'm thinking of either of three methods:

1. Inheriting from the `StaticClass` (it's a multiple inheritance then),
2. Defining a static member of `StaticClass` type,
3. Accessing `StaticClass<sizeof(T)>` in the methods directly.

All three methods will result in a similar source code (needing explicit specification of the class one way or another), and they all won't affect `sizeof(MainDerived<T>)`. I'm wondering if any of them has additional implications I should be aware of.

Comment: `I would like the members to be specific to a particular StaticClass<elem_size>` -> what that means?

Comment: What if two instances of `MainDerived` using different template parameter `T`, but the size of the two `T` types are the same? Then the static class will be the same even though `T` is different.

Comment: @Mr.Anubis, @JoachimPileborg: I edited the post to clarify that a bit. Shortly saying, that means there's one variable for each `elem_size`; and for different `T` with the same size, the variable should be shared.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see a similarity with the standard library's string class, which (in effect) has a typedef for a helper class with all static members, like

```
typedef std::char_traits<T>   traits_type;
```

and then uses `traits_type::copy`, `traits_type::assign`, etc, all through the rest of the code.

You could do something similar with your `StaticClass`.

```
typedef StaticClass<sizeof(T)>   sc;
```

and then use `sc::priv` to access to correct pointer for each class.